# How do I use userStorage with the new Dialogflow v2 API?

Tags: node.js, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

For example, in API v1, I could just do something like this:

```
app.userStorage.favoriteColor = blue;
```

And if I came back at a later session, I could access this value by doing this:

```
let myFavoriteColor = app.userStorage.favoriteColor;
```

---

I've been digging around at the API V2 documentation (which is almost non-existent in comparison to V1) and found where something similar is used in one of Google's examples seen [here](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/best-practices#personalize_the_conversation_with_user_preferences), where information is stored in `conv.user.storage.zip`:

```
app.intent('weather_report', function(conv) {
  let zip = conv.arguments.get('zipcode');
  conv.data.zip = zip;
  conv.ask(getWeatherReport(zip));
  conv.ask(new Confirmation(`Should I remember ${zip} for next time?`));
});

app.intent('remember_zip', function(conv, params, confirmation) {
  if (confirmation) {
    conv.user.storage.zip = conv.data.zip;
    conv.close('Great! See you next time.');
  } else conv.close('Ok, no problem.');
});
```

The saved zip code is then accessed here:

```
app.intent('weather_report', function(conv) {
  let zip = conv.arguments.get('zipcode');
  if (zip) {
    conv.close(getWeatherReport(zip));
  } else if (conv.userStorage.zip) {
    conv.ask(new SimpleResponse(getWeatherReport(conv.user.storage.zip)));
    conv.ask(new Suggestion('Try another zipcode'));
  } else {
    conv.ask('What\'s your zip code?');
  }
});

app.intent('provide_zip', function(conv) {
  conv.user.storage.zip = conv.arguments.get('zipcode');
  conv.close(getWeatherReport(conv.user.storage.zip));
});
```

Here, they're using both `conv.user.storage.zip` as well as `conv.userStorage.zip`, which was absent in the first block of code. Is that just a typo or is there something going on here that I'm not understanding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, that's a typo. The correct v2 property is **conv.user.storage** not conv.userStorage.

Thanks for pointing it out Geoff! The page should be updated today.